# Guardo en Mysql ceros ceros en los campos

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, jquery, ajax

Estoy elaborando un sistema de votación por estrellas y tengo lo siguiente:

HTML

```
<?php $ch = $_GET['id']; ?>

<div class="content">
  <div class="post-action">                 
    <select class='rating'
      id='rating_<?php echo $ch; ?>'
      data-id='rating_<?php echo $ch; ?>'
    >
      <option value="1">1</option>
      <option value="2">2</option>
      <option value="3">3</option>
      <option value="4">4</option>
      <option value="5">5</option>
    </select>
    <div style='clear: both;'></div><br><br>                
  </div>

</div>
```

JS

```
$(function() {
  $('.rating').barrating({
    theme: 'fontawesome-stars',
    onSelect: function(value, text, event) {

      // Get element id by data-id attribute
      var el = this;
      var el_id = el.$elem.data('id');

      // rating was selected by a user
      if (typeof(event) !== 'undefined') {

        var split_id = el_id.split("_");

        var postid = split_id[1];  // postid

        // AJAX Request
        $.ajax({
          url: 'rating_ajax.php',
          type: 'post',
          data: {postid:postid,rating:value},
          dataType: 'json',
          success: function(data){
            // Update average
            var average = data['averageRating'];
            $('#avgrating_'+postid).text(average);
          }
        });
      }
    }
  });
});
```

el rating_ajax.php

```
<?php 

session_start();
include_once '../cnx.php';

$usuario = $_SESSION['id'];
$postid = $_POST['postid'];
$rating = $_POST['rating'];

$query = 
  'SELECT COUNT(*) AS cntch 
   FROM ch_rating WHERE chid = "'.$postid.'" AND userid = "'.$usuario.'" ';
$rango = $mbd->prepare($query);
$rango -> execute();
$row = $rango->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$count = $row['cntch'];

if($count == 0){
  $insert = 
    'INSERT INTO ch_rating (chid,userid,rating) VALUES ("$postid","$usuario","$rating")';
  $add = $mbd->prepare($insert);
  $add->execute();

} else{
  $edit = 
    'UPDATE ch_rating SET rating=? WHERE userid="$usuario" AND chid="$postid" ';
  $editar = $mbd->prepare($edit);
  $editar->execute(array($rating));

}

$query = 
  "SELECT ROUND(AVG(rating),1) as averageRating FROM ch_rating WHERE chid = '".$postid."' ";
$state = $mbd->prepare($query);
$state -> execute();
$row = $state->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
$averageRating = $row['averageRating'];

$return_arr = array("averageRating"=>$averageRating);

echo json_encode($return_arr);
```

1. El HTML me pinta bien las estrellas, ya que traigo el articulo por id por GET y me muestra los votos que he insertado manualmente con anterioridad de cada articulo, el problema es cuando voy a votar por alguno con votos y sin votos..xD; si no tiene voto inserta en la base de datos puros ceros (0), si ya tiene votos no me hace el UPDATE, pero si que agarra los votos que guardo con ceros y modifica el voto (aquí si me modifica los votos de todos los que tienen cero,todos los cambia según el voto), no se que estaré haciendo mal.
2. No me esta enviando los datos al php para que capture y posteriormente pueda guardar o modificar según lo que selecciono al votar.

Que tendré mal?.

Comment: en el html, la falta de etiquetas `<?php ` y `?>` para `$ch = $_GET['id'];` es un error de copiado/pegado?

Comment: Hola, gracias por contestar, pero eso no es, copie esa parte del código pero en los originales esta bien..xD, completo.

Comment: Te funciono la solucion de @Jota ? revisa que es lo que envías antes de llamar al método ajax, puedes ponerle un log o ver en network `console.log({postid:postid,rating:value})`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Estás iniciando sesión `session_start();` cada vez que haces una llamada, cuidado con eso, la sesión debe de iniciarse una única vez.

El código JS quedaría:

```
 $(function() {
  $('.rating').barrating({
    theme: 'fontawesome-stars',
    onSelect: function(value, text, event) {
        if (typeof(event) !== 'undefined') {
            var postid= this.id.split("_")[1];
            $.post("rating_ajax.php",{postid:postid,rating:value}).done(function(data){
                $('#avgrating_'+postid).text(data['averageRating']);
            }).fail(function() {
                alert("Error");
            });
        }
   }});
});
```

Comment: Gracias, no lo he podido probar, hasta ahora pude revisar, voy a probarlo. Gracias.